# Table inside inline-flex incorrect sizing in Safari

Tags: html, css, flexbox, safari

When a `<table>` is inside an inline-flex container with flex-direction column, the [cross-size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#cross-size) of the table is different in Safari compared to Chrome and Firefox. I'm assuming Safari is incorrect here—who would want a squished table like that by default?

**Safari 16.3**

[image: Safari screenshot]

**Chrome 110 and Firefox 110**

[image: Chrome and Firefox screenshot]

Is Safari wrong here? If not, why is its size that?

I have read [Cross Size Determination](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#cross-sizing) in the flexbox spec but I can't tell how it relates to this specific example.

I have also checked the [WebKit Bug Tracker](https://bugs.webkit.org/) but I couldn't find anything related to inline-flex and tables.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: `Is Safari wrong here?` Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this is a WebKit bug and it has been [reported to Apple](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=253922).

I have tested it in Safari 17.2.1 and it is fixed in that version.